# My list comes out double when I enter more than one letter in my answer

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

```
item=[]

a = raw_input('enter 1st item')
for x in a :
    item.append(a)

b = raw_input('enter 2nd item')
for x in b :
    item.append(b)

c = raw_input('enter 3rd item')
for x in c :
    item.append(c)

print item
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are appending the whole string `len(str)` times?

Comment: Just append values without for loop

Comment: It works without the for loop but the question I'm doing said I must make use of a for or while loop

Comment: Part of the Question:
From the problem description I hope you can logically see that a program like this will use: 
 - raw_input to get user input.
- a list that initially starts out as empty, but then grows as items are appended.
 - a for OR while loop to track how many items have been added already.
 - a print statement after the loop to print out what items have been added.

Comment: What are you trying to do in this code? Do you want to append the inputs which you are entering into the list or you want to do something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
    item=[]

    a = raw_input('enter 1st item')
    for x in a :
        item.append(x)

    b = raw_input('enter 2nd item')
    for x in b :
        item.append(x)

    c = raw_input('enter 3rd item')
    for x in c :
        item.append(x)

print item
```

Comment: You were appending the entire string entered by user as many time there is characters in input string

Comment: How can I append only some of the string?

Comment: Not some of the string first try code i have posted then tell me your problem

Comment: Here you are appending the string character by character in the list.

Comment: So what you required actually.